Locating Birth Certificate City in Oviedo
I am trying to locate the Birth Certificate or Fe de Bautismo for my grandfather. I have his full name and place of birth said Oviedo, Asturias. I have his DOB although the date and month might be reversed as in USA. However, Oviedo is asking me to narrow it down to a city ... not sure how i may do this. I also have both of his parents names. Where should I look to narrow down his city and then confirm his DOB.?

can you provide birth year? is DOB from an official document or word of mouth only?

A good starting point for Spain research and records is https://www.thefhguide.com/project-9-spain.html  You could also go to the FamilySearch Wiki at:https://www.familysearch.org/en/wiki/index.php?search=Oviedo%2C%20Asturias&title=Special%3ASearch&fulltext=1&ns0=1&ns12=1&ns14=1&ns3100=1.  There you will find two useful sites fpr Oviedo, Asturias with lots of information.  You could also do a genearal search for Spain in the Research Wiki.  Third, you can go to the FamilySearch Catalog at: https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=5061058&query=%2Bplace%3A%22Spain%2C%20Asturias%2C%20Oviedo%22 or once again you can enter just Spain. Lastly, ChatGPT is a great AI tool for getting genealogy sites.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

As has been commented elsewhere, this "user" appears to be posting AI-generated content.
